# I got an error: (POST net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR)

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I'm trying to deploy model (deep learning, classification for cats and dogs) using Flask on web app. When I upload an image of cat or a dog, I should get some predictions, but get only an error. I have code written in python and javascript. 
This is an error: 
"jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 POST https://127.0.0.1:5000/static/predict.html net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Predict the bottle</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="image-selector">
    <button id="predict-button">Predict</button>
    <p style="font-weight: bold;">Predictions</p>
    <p>Dog: <span id="dog-prediction"></span></p>
    <p>Cat: <span id="cat-prediction"></span></p>
    <div style="width: 400px; height: 400px;">
        <img src="" id="selected-image" style="max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%;">
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        let base64Image;
        console.log("* * * Page is refreshed");

        $("#image-selector").change(function() {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                let dataURL = reader.result;
                $('#selected-image').attr("src", dataURL);
                base64Image = dataURL.replace("data:image/png;base64", "");
                //console.log(base64Image);
                console.log("* * * Image is uploaded");
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL($('#image-selector')[0].files[0]);
            $('#dog-prediction').text("");
            $('#cat-prediction').text("");
        });
        $("#predict-button").click(function(event){
            console.log("* * * Button 'Prediction' is clicked");
            let message = {
                image: base64Image
            }
            console.log("* * * Message(image):" , message);

            $.post("https://127.0.0.1:5000/static/predict.html", JSON.stringify(message), function(response){
                $("#dog-prediction").text(response.prediction.dog.toFixed(6));
                $("#cat-prediction").text(response.prediction.cat.toFixed(6));
                console.log("* * * Response ", response);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```py
import base64
import numpy as np
import io

import keras
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from flask import request
from flask import jsonify
from flask import Flask
from PIL import Image

app = Flask(__name__)


def get_model():
    global model
    model = load_model('VGG16_cats_and_dogs.h5')
    print(" * Model loaded!")


def preprocess_image(image, target_size):
    if image.mode != "RGB":
        image = image.convert("RGB")
    image = image.resize(target_size)
    image = img_to_array(image)
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

    return image


print(" * Loading Keras model...")
get_model()


@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    message = request.get_json(force=True)
    encoded = message['image']
    decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded)
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(decoded))
    processed_image = preprocess_image(image, target_size=(224, 224))

    prediction = model.predict(processed_image).toList()

    response = {
        'Prediction': {
            'dog': prediction[0][0],
            'cat': prediction[0][1]
        }
    }
    return jsonify(response)
```

Comment: Did it work in postman? Since it's localhost, try changing post request in jquery from https to http and see if it works

Comment: I tried but it's not working